# Concatenate a string instead a replacement

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I'm filtering certain column from my table:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>*/*"
```

I want everything that doesn't contain `/`

Then I apply `Selection.Replace` in the intention of concatenating the contents of that cell with `/SUP`

```
Selection.Replace What:="???", Replacement:="???/SUP", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But it isn't working. The output I expected is:

```
cellWith/ --- replace --- cellWith/
cellWithout --- replace --- cellWithout/SUP
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Would you not want to loop through your content and just use `if right(cells(i,3).value,1) <> "/" then cells(i,3).value = cells(i,3).value & "/SUP"` ?  As written, you are searching for `???` and replacing it, which wouldn't work as that exact string doesn't appear in your content.

Comment: So, you are replacing the text `"???"` with `"???/SUP"` - do your cells **actually** end with three question marks???

Comment: @Cyril Since the query is "does not contain `"/"`", I would suggest `If InStr(cells(i,3).Value,"/")>0 Then` instead

Comment: Good point, @Chronocidal , though you don't need the `>0` as InStr returns boolean.

Comment: @Chronocidal I'm using `???` as any three characters

Comment: @Cyril I haven't considered the option to loop the content because I thought that with this method would be more performatic

Comment: @GabrielHardoim It looks like you would need a loop regardless, though if you are worried about performance, use a variant array to store the values in the column so the `if` check can be done inside of VBA, then change the cell value to be that of the array & "/lsup", e.g., `cell(i+1,3).value = arr(i,1) & "/SUP"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `AutoFilter` then you need to use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and just add `"/SUP"` to the end of the cells value.

```
Dim cel As Range
With ActiveSheet 'It's better to use the worksheet("Name") or a worksheet variable
    'Filter 
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>*/*"
    'Loop through each visible cell in the range 
    For Each cel In .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'Concatenate the cells value and "/SUP"
        cel.Value = Left(cel.Value, Len(cel.Value)) + "/SUP"
    Next cel 'Loop
End With
```

Added_Just to be thorough; If you wanted to replace the last three characters in the cell and add `/SUP`, you can change this line...

```
cel.Value = Left(cel.Value, Len(cel.Value)) + "/SUP"
```

to...

```
cel.Value = Left(cel.Value, Len(cel.Value) - 3) + "/SUP"
```

Comment: Should the `+` in the cel.value line be an ampersand (`&`)?

Answer (score 1):

Related to my last comment, loop using variant array, which should be quick as the check is performed by VBA, not referencing the cells each time:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long, arr As Variant
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, 1)).Value
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        If InStr(arr(i, 1), "/") Then
            Cells(i, 2).Value = arr(i, 1)
        Else
            Cells(i, 2).Value = arr(i, 1) & "/SUP"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I output the values into column b (starting with row 2 in the loop for visualization purposes), which looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Range.Replace is going to work for your intended use case here.  Best bet is to loop over the data and append where necessary.  Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aData() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With ws.Range("C2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data

        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            aData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            aData = .Value
        End If

        For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
            If InStr(1, aData(i, 1), "/", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then aData(i, 1) = aData(i, 1) & "/SUP"
        Next i

        .Value = aData
    End With

End Sub
```